# Calling Function in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to call a function from ExtJS popup but it is not identifying the method. I guess I am missing the scope. Please take a look at the code below and suggest where am I going wrong.
In the below code section the handler: function () is not calling the intended method.

```
Ext.define('App.controller.MakerController', {
extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

models : [],

stores : [],

views : [ 'makertabpanel' ],

init : function() {
    this.control({
        'makertabpanel button[name= addNewUser]' : {
            click : this.openDialog
        },

        'makertabpanel button[name= modifyUser]' : {
            click : this.openmodifyDialog
        }
    });
},
openmodifyDialog : function() {
    var userinfoGrid = Ext.getCmp('userinfogridID');
    if (userinfoGrid.getSelectionModel().hasSelection()) {
       var row = userinfoGrid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
       console.log(row.get('id'));

       var name = Ext.getCmp('usernameID').setValue(row.get('id'));
       var name = Ext.getCmp('userFirstName').setValue(row.get('fname'));
       var name = Ext.getCmp('userLastName').setValue(row.get('lname'));
    }

    this.openDialog();
},
openDialog : function() {
    //var that = this;
    var dialog = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        title : 'Permission Uesr',
        itemId : 'adduserpopup',
        id : 'adduserpopup',
        closeAction: 'hide',
        modal : true,
        width : 1000,
        height : 400,
         layout       : {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch',
                padding: 5
            },
        resizable : false,
        items : [ createuserinformation,itemselectorGrid],
        buttons : [ {
            text : 'Save',
            id : 'okbutton',

            handler: function () {
                console.log("Save user Data 1 :"+this.up('window'));
                //this.up('window').saveUserData();
                this.saveUserData();  // this is not working
            }
        } ]
    });
    dialog.show();
},
saveUserData : function() {
    alert("Save user Data");
    // create an AJAX request
}
});
```

Comment: Misiing `scope: this` on the button config.

Comment: This works. Thanks !! Is there any other way of doing this which is better ?

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
openDialog : function() {
    var me = this;
    var dialog = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        title : 'Permission Uesr',
        itemId : 'adduserpopup',
        id : 'adduserpopup',
        closeAction: 'hide',
        modal : true,
        width : 1000,
        height : 400,
         layout       : {
                type: 'vbox',
                align: 'stretch',
                padding: 5
            },
        resizable : false,
        items : [ createuserinformation,itemselectorGrid],
        buttons : [ {
            text : 'Save',
            id : 'okbutton',

            handler: function () {
                console.log("Save user Data 1 :"+this.up('window'));

                me.saveUserData();  // instead using this use local variable me
            }
        } ]
    });
    dialog.show();
},
```